# Google Map api added span(BESbewy) at page load, causing horizontal Scrolling in RTL websites, how to fix it?

Tags: api, dictionary

I tried this code:

```
    var clearDamnSpan = setInterval(function () {
  $('body > span').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === 'BESbewy') {
      //if you remove the element, You might see errors in Google Chrome
      $(this).hide();
      clearInterval(clearDamnSpan);
    }
  });
}, 500);
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(clearDamnSpan);
}, 50000);
```

it didn't work. so what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the word "BESbswy" instead of "BESbewy" in the code above.